# Convert Date of Birth to Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, date

I have a standard date in ISO format: 1950-01-01 (date of birth)

And I need to convert it to a javascript object, so I can convert it to US Format (01/01/1050).

However when I convert it, it changes it to: Sat Dec 31 1949 17:00:00 GMT-0700

I just need it converted, without any offsets, or changes.  If they were born on x day, it is x day.

Here is what I am doing currently:

```
$("#dob1").val( new Date(client.dob1).toLocaleDateString('en', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' }) )
```

client.dob1 = "1950-01-01"

**Final working result, in case anyone stumbles upon this:**

```
$("#dob1").val( new Date(client.dob1).toLocaleDateString('en', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', timeZone: "UTC" }) )
```

Comment: Looks like it is parsed in UTC, while the default string output is in your local timezone. Just use the UTC methods when formatting to US and you'll get 01.01.1950

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript Date timezone issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174810/javascript-date-timezone-issue)

Comment: @Bergi - Unfortunately, that is an implementation detail that has changed between ES5 & ES6.  Best not to rely on it, or get caught when new standards start being rolled out.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Yeah, sure, one should also ensure that the date is parsed in UTC (using whatever means)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also replace the dashes with slashes, and make a `new Date()` from the resulting string.

(some code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29185654/2033574)

```js
// Manually
date1 = new Date("1950/01/01")

// Or programmatically:
dashDate = "1950-01-01"
date2 = new Date(dashDate.replace(/-/g, '/'))

// Same output
document.write(date1 + "<br>" + date2)
```

Comment: Im marking this as correct, but I prefer Bergi's answer of: toLocaleDateString('en', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', timeZone: "UTC" })

Answer (score 0):

You can simple create a Date object like this.

```
new Date('2015-10-13')
```

You can read here more about [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Right, but when I do that, it changes the date back 7 hours, making the date always wrong.  SInce we are talking about a specific date, not a datetime.

Comment: Try using / instead of -
See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174810/javascript-date-timezone-issue

Comment: @triunenature: it's not back 7 hours. It's still 01. 01. 1950 00:00 **UTC**. Only your output is in a different timezone.

Comment: it's because of your local time zone.

Comment: @FievelYaltsen, That worked, make that an answer and I'll accept it.  It's frusterating that I can't just tell js to give me the date I supplied it.

Comment: @Bergi, I understand that it is correct as the object.  But I need the *output* to be correct.  

It's like saying, well the system is right, but it isn't showing right.  Doesn't actually help me right?  I dont care about the parser, I just need it to give me the date I used.

Comment: @triunenature: Just pass `timeZone: "UTC"` to the [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) then.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks so much!  That's the part I was missing.  It's actually a sane answer. Clearly I need to read the docs more.