# angular-bootstrap date picker shows incorrect date for 'yyyy-mm-dd' format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datepicker, angular-bootstrap

We're storing birth dates in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd`. When this format is provided to the [angular-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) date picker, it selects the incorrect date in the popup. Converting it to a date object causes both the display and selection to be incorrect. [See my plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/eI8bn6Qr6fBcUJ33fv8Y?p=preview) for examples (ignore validation stuff, that's a whole other issue).

```
// Displays '2015-09-25', but 24th is selected
var date = '2015-09-25';

// Displays '2015-09-24', selects 24th
var date = new Date("2015-09-25");
```

Comment: The problem is timezones. The model is using `UTC` timezone - but the selected date is using the local timezone.

Answer (score 3):

From [javascript Date timezone issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174810/javascript-date-timezone-issue): "In JavaScript, a value in the format of YYYY-MM-DD is interpreted as a UTC value, rather than a local-time value."

One workaround is to replace the hyphens with slashes:

```
var s = "2015-09-25";
var dt = new Date(s.replace(/-/g, '/'));
```

I would recommend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) though. It works for me and I had the same problem with a javascript datepicker.

```
var s = "2015-09-25";
var dt = moment(s, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate();
```

Comment: Instead of linking to other answers it is better to mark questions as duplicates

Comment: +1 To using Moment.js for parsing dates. When doing that, make sure you pass a specific format string: `moment(str, fmt)`. This is key. From the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/): "Warning: Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers. / For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String + Format."