# JavaScript date timezone strange behavior

Tags: javascript, date, time, timezone, difference

when I build a date form this ISO String "2016-02-01T16:00:00Z" I got  Mon Feb 01 2016 17:00:00 GMT+0100

It seams that js is adding a hour for some reasons.

I think its a Timezone thing... but how can I fix this?

just do

```js
var date = new Date('2016-02-01T16:00:00Z');
alert(date);
```

Comment: Have the answers below helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to specifications, the ISO date string is parsed as UTC+0000, which is indicated by the `Z` char at the end.

> Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset

When you indicate a date time string for the `Date()` constructor, it's parsed  in UTC.
The method `Date.prototype.toString()` is formatting the date according to your timezone, which may differ from UTC. Because of that you get this offset.

It's possible to indicate a custom timezone at the end of an ISO string with `±hh:mm`:

```
var d = new Date('2016-02-01T16:00:00+01:00');
d.toString() // will print "Feb 01 2016 16:00:00 GMT+0100", if you're in GMT+01:00
```

Comment: +1, however, parsing strings with the Date constructor is unreliable and not recommended, far better to manually parse strings (a library can help but isn't necessary in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript takes your datetime string, parses it in the timezone indicated (UTC), but then *displays* it in your current timezone.

When I run your code snippet, I get GMT-05:00 (EST).

So it's not adding an hour. It's just outputting the date in your local timezone.

Comment: That's correct, it's the same time printed in different ways. This can be seen by printing date.toString() and date.toUTCString()

Answer (score 0):

You need take into consideration the TimeZoneOffset `Date.getTimezoneOffset()` to show same date in different time zones. For example get offset in minutes convert to hours and add it to you time, or write function to convert date with depend time zone offset Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174810/javascript-date-timezone-issue/38742940#38742940)