# handle dates properly with different timezones in a React App

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a react application that stores and retrieves datetimes, then disable the unavalaible dates and times.

When the dates are saved from a calendar into the Database, they are **one hour late**.

When I retrieve the dates from the database, they are **2 hours late**.

Imagine I have chosen this dateTime from the calendar : **24 Aug 2023 at 21:30**

In the database it is saved as : **2023-08-24 20:30:00.000**

When I retrieve it I get : **2023-08-24T19:30:00.000Z**

When I wrap it in a Date object I get: **Date Thu Aug 24 2023 20:30:00 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)**.

```js
console.log(res.data[0].dateTime) // 2023-08-24T19:30:00.000Z
console.log(new Date(res.data[0].dateTime)) //Date Thu Aug 24 2023 20:30:00 GMT+0100 (UTC+01:00)
```

When I display it using **date-fns** I get **20:30** instead of **21:30**

```js
<td className="border border-neutral-500 p-3">
        {format(new Date(res.data[0].dateTime), 'kk:mm')}
</td>
```

Note that when I deployed this app on LWS which has a different timezone, the dates are 2 hours late, and I cannot update the system timezone.

Please help me understand how can I handle these dates properly with **different timezones** in order to have the same date and times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript Date timezone issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29174810/javascript-date-timezone-issue)

Comment: No it doesn't..

Comment: Always (I repeat - **always**) save dates and times in UTC format in the server. If you want to render it in HTML, parse the devices' time-zones and convert the stored dates and times accordingly. When you save it in the server, make sure you parse the time-zones and convert it to UTC.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

- database
- application server
- browser

## Database

Your DB is set to use a specific timezone. I will assume that it's UTC, because it's a standard, but, if it's not the case, then it makes sense to switch to UTC, but you are not obliged to do so. Remember, your clients are unlikely to directly access this data nor the users, so you would do well to choose the timezone which will be better for you from technical point of view and ensure that the data is humanly understandable (a.k.a. show the date according to the user's timezone) on a different level.

## Application

Your application server also has a timezone, which is not necessarily the same as the timezone of the database. You would do yourself a favor if you set your application's timezone to be the very same as the database timezone. Of course, your application may have to generate reports, which are to be read by people, so you will need to convert the database/app date/time to the timezone of the audience of the report.

## Browser

This part, like your reports that may be generated at the server are to be shown to humans, so you will need two functions to convert to app/db timezone and back:

```js
function toUTC(value) {
    return (new Date(value).toUTCString());
}

function fromUTC(value) {
    return (new Date(value));
}

function handle(value) {
    let context = document.getElementById("output").querySelectorAll("p");
    context[0].innerHTML = `UTC time: ${toUTC(value)}`;
    context[1].innerHTML = `Your time: ${fromUTC(toUTC(value))}`;
}
```

```html
<label for="birthdaytime">Birthday (date and time):</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="birthdaytime" name="birthdaytime" oninput="handle(this.value);">
  <br>
  <div id="output">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
  </div>
```

where `toUTC` converts the value you have chosen at the `input` into a UTC string. This string is to be sent to the server. Once the server sends you a UTC string, you can convert it into your local date via `fromUTC`.

If you use some other timezone than UTC at your server, then you will need to use `toLocaleString`, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

This is an added complexity in comparison to the case when you would use UTC, so I would avoid it if possible, but it's a solvable issue if using UTC at the server is not an option for some reason.